# Anorm: WHERE condition, conditionally

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4, anorm

Consider a repository/DAO method like this, which works great:

```
def countReports(customerId: Long, createdSince: ZonedDateTime) =
  DB.withConnection {
    implicit c =>
      SQL"""SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM report
            WHERE customer_id = $customerId
            AND created >= $createdSince
         """.as(scalar[Int].single)
  }
```

But what if the method is defined with **optional parameters**:

```
def countReports(customerId: Option[Long], createdSince: Option[ZonedDateTime])
```

Point being, if either optional argument is present, use it in filtering the results (as shown above), and otherwise (in case it is `None`) simply leave out the corresponding WHERE condition.

**What's the simplest way to write this method with optional WHERE conditions?** As Anorm newbie I was struggling to find an example of this, but I suppose there must be *some* sensible way to do it (that is, without duplicating the SQL for each combination of present/missing arguments).

Note that the `java.time.ZonedDateTime` instance maps perfectly and automatically into Postgres `timestamptz` when used inside the Anorm `SQL` call. (Trying to extract the WHERE condition as a string, outside `SQL`, created with normal string interpolation did not work; `toString` produces a representation not understood by the database.)

Play 2.4.4

Comment: I've played with different options at a [GitHub test repo](https://github.com/jonikarppinen/play-testbench/blob/master/app/repositories/ReportRepository.scala); feel free to fork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got this **[simpler approach posted by Joel Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18308023/56285)** to work in my example case, also with ZonedDateTime!

```
def countReports(customerId: Option[Long], createdSince: Option[ZonedDateTime]) =
  DB.withConnection {
    implicit c =>
      SQL( """
          SELECT count(*) FROM report
          WHERE ({customerId} is null or customer_id = {customerId})
          AND ({created}::timestamptz is null or created >= {created})
           """)
        .on('customerId -> customerId, 'created -> createdSince)
        .as(scalar[Int].singleOpt).getOrElse(0)
  }
```

The tricky part is having to use `{created}::timestamptz` in the null check. As [Joel commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516613/anorm-dynamic-filters/18308023#comment57178951_18308023), this is needed to work around a [PostgreSQL driver issue](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Pine.BSO.4.63.0608292151450.28706@leary2.csoft.net).

Apparently the cast is needed only for *timestamp* types, and the simpler way (`{customerId} is null`) works with everything else. Also, comment if you know whether other databases require something like this, or if this is a Postgres-only peculiarity.

(While [wwkudu's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34081826/56285) also works fine, this definitely is cleaner, as you can see [comparing them side to side](https://github.com/jonikarppinen/play-testbench/blob/master/app/repositories/ReportRepository.scala#L49) in a full example.)

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to set up filter clauses such as

```
val customerClause =
  if (customerId.isEmpty) ""
  else " and customer_id={customerId}"
```

then substitute these into you SQL:

```
SQL(s"""
  select count(*)
    from report
    where true
      $customerClause
      $createdClause
""")
.on('customerId -> customerId, 
  'createdSince -> createdSince)
.as(scalar[Int].singleOpt).getOrElse(0)
```

Using `{variable}` as opposed to `$variable` is I think preferable as it reduces the risk of SQL injection attacks where someone potentially calls your method with a malicious string. Anorm doesn't mind if you have additional symbols that aren't referenced in the SQL (i.e. if a clause string is empty). Lastly, depending on the database(?), a count might return no rows, so I use singleOpt rather than single.

I'm curious as to what other answers you receive.

Edit: Anorm interpolation (i.e. SQL"...", an interpolation implementation beyond Scala's s"...", f"..." and raw"...") [was introduced](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/Q7XetWpD0A8) to allow the use `$variable` as equivalent to `{variable}` with `.on`. And from Play 2.4, Scala and Anorm interpolation can be mixed using `$` for Anorm (SQL parameter/variable) and `#$` for Scala (plain string). And indeed this works well, as long as the Scala interpolated string does not contains references to an SQL parameter. The only way, in 2.4.4, I could find to use a variable in an Scala interpolated string when using Anorm interpolation, was:

```
val limitClause = if (nameFilter="") "" else s"where name>'$nameFilter'"
SQL"select * from tab #$limitClause order by name"
```

But this is vulnerable to SQL injection (e.g. a string like `it's` will cause a runtime syntax exception). So, in the case of variables inside interpolated strings, it seems it is necessary to use the "traditional" `.on` approach with only Scala interpolation:

```
val limitClause = if (nameFilter="") "" else "where name>{nameFilter}"
SQL(s"select * from tab $limitClause order by name").on('limitClause -> limitClause)
```

Perhaps in the future Anorm interpolation could be extended to parse the interpolated string for variables?

Edit2: I'm finding there are some tables where the number of attributes that might or might not be included in the query changes from time to time. For these cases I'm defining a context class, e.g. `CustomerContext`. In this case class there are `lazy val`s for the different clauses that affect the sql. Callers of the sql method must supply a `CustomerContext`, and the sql will then have inclusions such as `${context.createdClause}` and so on. This helps give a consistency, as I end up using the context in other places (such as total record count for paging, etc.).

Comment: There is no more risk of SQL injection by using Anorm interpolation `SQL"..."` (which is not standard string interpolation and) which set the parameter values in the same way

Comment: Thanks, this approach is pretty clean, and it does work! What I initially missed was that you're using `SQL(""" """)` instead of `SQL""" """`. [These are NOT the same](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28484728/56285), as I learned the hard way after fighting with *ERROR: syntax error at or near "{"* for some time. You can't use the `{customerId}` syntax inside `SQL""" """`.

Comment: @cchantep: For this "conditional condition" case, to me it seems that I  need the `{customerId}` and `.on()` approach to get it working. You can prove me wrong, if you like, by posting an answer that's equivalent but implemented with `SQL"..."` :)

Comment: (And of course I meant `SQL(s""" """)` above—the `s` is required to get `$customerClause` etc properly replaced.)

Comment: Interesting - I had not seen the SQL "..." format. Tks for that.

Comment: Seems there are some 2.3/2.4 differences - just [reading about #$ for example](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.2/ScalaAnorm#SQL-queries-using-String-Interpolation).

Comment: `#$` allows to mix string interpolation inside Anorm interpolation, safely.

Comment: I found a potentially cleaner solution, but couldn't get it working with ZonedDateTime (no problem with Strings and Longs): http://stackoverflow.com/a/18308023/56285

Comment: @Jonik, those questions seems to address shortening of the on clauses.

Comment: The linked answer *is* essentially about the same thing as what I'm looking for, but as noted, I couldn't get it to work with ZonedDateTime. (If my question only had `customerId: Long` then that solution would work fine.) I have a [GitHub repo with full test case](https://github.com/jonikarppinen/play-testbench/blob/master/app/repositories/ReportRepository.scala) if you wanna try it out.